# Get ID from string php wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a URL string of images divided by "|" and I would like a php function that reading the string separate the images and divide them with "," to use a wordpress gallery component

http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/large-IMG_5367.jpg|http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/large-IMG_5376.jpg|http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/large-IMG_6324.jpg

I tried to create a php shortcode called get id from string

```
   /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Shortcode | get_id_from_string
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


add_shortcode('get_id_from_string', 'function_get_id_from_string');
function function_get_id_from_string($atts) {
  global $wpdb;
  $return_value = '';

  $url_array = explode('|', $atts['urls']);

  foreach ($url_array as &$url) {
    $return_value .= $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $url))[0] . ',';

  }

  return rtrim($return_value, ',');
}
```

But it does not work, has anyone already done something like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you echo your sql query ?

Comment: I apologize that it was to check if it works

Comment: What is the output of your code, or is the code itself is not able to run properly. You will need to step through the debugger to identify the variables and query being generated. Will be better if you set the sql query in a separate variable to ease debugging rather than constructing inline the function call

Comment: You need some debugging. f.e. guid='%s' is wrong. it should be guid=%s - without any quote.

Comment: It just does not work, I tried to debug but it does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

Try below cod, 
If URL found in database it will return `ID` and add in `$return_value` variable.

```
add_shortcode('get_id_from_string', 'function_get_id_from_string');
function function_get_id_from_string($atts)
{
    global $wpdb;
    //$imagestr = "http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/large-IMG_5367.jpg|http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/large-IMG_5376.jpg|http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/large-IMG_6324.jpg";
    $imagestr = $atts['urls'];
    $url_array = explode("|", $imagestr);
    $return_value = [];
    foreach ($url_array as $url) {
        $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s'", $url);
        $result = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($query, $url), ARRAY_A);
        if (!empty($result))
            $return_value[] = $result[0];
    }
    $images_ids = implode(",", $return_value);
    return ($images_ids);
}
```

Comment: It seems to work but as output only leaves me an image "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/uploads/2018/02/large-A.jpg" Could it be that he was wrong to insert the shortcode? [gallery link="file" columns="5" ids="[get_id_from_string urls='{!{types field='galleria-immagini' separator=',' output='raw'}!}

Comment: it will return comma separated list of images if found in database. may be there was use-age issue of shortcode.